# Eigenvalues of $AB$ vs eigenvalues of $BA$ (incl. infinite-dimensional case)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am reading Curtis - Abstract Linear Algebra to pump up my knowledge a little bit and I found exercise I.F.7 (page 41),
where I am asked to prove the following:

> If $V$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and $A, B \in End(V)$, then $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues.

I am seeking a confirmation that this result as stated is indeed *false* and that a corrected version could be the following:

> $AB$ and $BA$ have the same *non-zero* eigenvalues.
>   If $V$ is finite dimensional, then $AB$ and $BA$ have the same eigenvalues.

The proof of the first assertion should go as follows.

If $\lambda$ is a non-zero eigenvalue of $AB$, then
$$
AB v = \lambda v
$$
for some non-zero $v \in V$ and since $\lambda \neq 0$, $Bv$ cannot be zero.
So we can apply $B$ to both sides and get
$$
BA (Bv) = \lambda (Bv)
$$
which means that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $BA$

The second assertion is in general false in an infinite-dimensional space.

For example take $V = \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$,
$A(v_1, v_2, \dots) = (0, v_1, v_2, \dots)$ and
$B(v_1, v_2, \dots) = (v_2, \dots)$
Then $0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$ (because $AB(v) = (0, v_2, v_3, \dots)$ has clearly a non-trivial kernel)
but is definitely not an eigenvalue of $BA$ since $BA = I$.

To prove the second assertion, we could reason like the following.

In general, if $AB$ is injective (resp., surjective) then $B$ is injective (resp., $A$ is surjective),
which implies that if $AB$ is invertible then $B$ is injective and $A$ is surjective.
If $V$ is finite dimensional, we can make this result stronger and say that invertibility of $AB$ implies invertibility of both $A$ and $B$, thus of $BA$.
So in the finite-dimensional case, if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$, then $AB$ is not injective, i.e. not invertible, then (by the contrapositive of the result above) $BA$ is not invertible, i.e. not injective, which is to say that $0$ is also an eigenvalue of $BA$.

Comment: Yes, that's all fine. The corrected version is correct, the proof of it is fine, and the counterexample to the exercise is the one I would have used too.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks a lot. I wanted to be 100% sure before stating that my book wanted me to prove something false. I m not sure how it works in these cases.. if you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: One way it would is to [answer the question yourself](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29126/248286). Answer the question, "Is this exercise wrong?", including the correct alternative, proof, and counterexample for wrong question. Then I'll give you a +1.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you.. actually the one who takes credit should be you.. :):) in any case I ve done as you suggested here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3315579/121348

Comment: At this point, should this question be deleted?

Comment: Proof verification can be problematic like this, yes. One way to salvage this is to edit your question into a "question" and post your proof as an "answer". If this is a duplicate, I'd just delete this and post an answer on the appropriate question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila This was not a duplicate (to the best of my knowledge) when I first posted the question. Then, following Theo's advice, I posted a new question and gave myself an answer,: it was done here math.stackexchange.com/a/3315579/121348. So, as of now this post is a duplicate of the new post I created. So we can delete this post.